# Android Room query objects with at least one item existing from another list

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

let me show some code first. I have list of Symptom objects in database:

```
val symptomA = Symptom(id = 0, name = "SymptomA")
val symptomB = Symptom(id = 1, name = "SymptomB")
val symptomC = Symptom(id = 2, name = "SymptomC")
val symptomD = Symptom(id = 3, name = "SymptomD")
```

I have also list of Disease objects in database:

```
val diseaseA = Disease(id = 0, name = "DiseaseA", listOfSymptoms = listOf(0, 1))
val diseaseB = Disease(id = 1, name = "DiseaseB", listOfSymptoms = listOf(1, 2, 3))
val diseaseC = Disease(id = 2, name = "DiseaseC", listOfSymptoms = listOf(0, 2))
val diseaseD = Disease(id = 3, name = "DiseaseD", listOfSymptoms = listOf(3))
```

Some classes I'm using:

**Disease**

```
@Entity(tableName = "diseases")
data class Disease(
    @PrimaryKey @NotNull val id: Int,
    @NotNull val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "symptoms_ids") val symptomsIds: String,
    ...)
```

**SymptomsDao**

```
@Dao
interface DiseaseDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM diseases WHERE id LIKE :id LIMIT 1")
    fun getDisease(id: Int): Disease

    @Query("SELECT * FROM diseases")
    fun getAllDiseases(): LiveData<List<Disease>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM diseases WHERE symptoms_ids IN (:symptoms)")
    fun getDiseasesWithSymptoms(symptoms: List<Int>): LiveData<List<Disease>>
    // The query from question ^
}
```

**Converter (used in db class to convert String into list)**

```
class Converter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromString(stringListString: String) = stringListString.split(";").map { it.toInt() }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toString(stringList: List<Int>) = stringList.joinToString(";")
}
```

### Question

Is it possible to query by Room all diseases with at least one symptom id from list? I'm using MVVM pattern, is that possible to do it in DAO or should I create a function in Repository or ViewModel class?

**First example:**

input = `listOf(0)`

result = `listOf(diseaseA, diseaseC)`

**Second example:**

input = `listOf(1, 2)`

result = `listOf(diseaseA, diseaseB, diseaseC)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do it in the `ViewModel` as SQL/Room doesn't understand `List` types and cannot perform such a check for you.

```kotlin
fun getDiseasesWithSymptoms(symptoms: List<Int>): LiveData<List<Disease>> {
    return Transformations.map(diseaseDao.getAllDiseases()) { diseases ->
        diseases.filter { disease ->
            disease.listOfSymptoms.any { symptoms.contains(it)}
        }
    }
}
```